# Acetic acid in vinegar

Tags: concentration, mole

How do I calculate the number of moles of acetic acid present in 25 mL of a 10% vinegar solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

10% solution means 10 g of solute in 100 mL of the solution.  So we have 10 g $\ce{CH3COOH}$ in 100 mL. Therefore , we have 2.5 g in 25 mL.
No. of moles of acetic acid = $\frac{m}{M}$
No. of moles = $\frac{2.5}{60}$ = 0.0417 moles of $\ce{CH3COOH}$.